# Postgresql db:create doesn't work because password authentication failed for superuser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I am working on a rails website which uses postgresql databse. My config/database.yml looks like this.

```
     default: &default
      adapter: postgresql
      pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
      timeout: 5000
      username: postgres
      password: mypassword
      host: localhost
     development:
      <<: *default
      database: my_db_development
     test:
      <<: *default
        database: my_db_test

     production:
       <<: *default
       database: my_db_production
```

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong but I just installed postgresql on my computer (Windows 10) and during installation it asked "please provide a password for the database superuser (postgres)" and that was when i entered "mypassword". What goes in the username and password? I am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

i found the similiar problem about [Forgotten PostgreSQL Windows password](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44586/forgotten-postgresql-windows-password), hope that will help to solve your problem.